# Vuejs - Use key in object loop as option value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a `colors` object, that contains exactly what you think:

```
{
  "RD": "Red",
  "BL": "Blue",
  "GR": "Green",
  "YW": "Yellow"
}
```

I have a `select` dropdown that creates an `<option>` for each color in the `colors` object:

```
<select v-model="colors">
  <option selected>SELECT A COLOR</select> // default value
  <option v-for="(color, key) in colors">{{ color }}</option>
</select>
```

This displays great in the dropdown.

- The `{{ color }}` expression shows the name, i.e. '**Blue**'
- If I were to instead use `{{ key }}` as the expression, it would read '**BR**'

**Challenge:**

- I am struggling to assign `key` to the `option` `value` attribute

For example:

```
<option v-for="(color, key) in colors" :key="key">{{ color }}</option>
```

In this case `key` is actually 'Blue' instead of 'BR', and switching it to `color` shows the same thing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following with setting value property via `:value`:

```
<select v-model="colors">
  <option selected>SELECT A COLOR</select>
  <option v-for="(color, key) in colors" :value="key" :key="key">{{ color }}</option>
</select>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r34z1hs7/) demonstrating the functionality.

Hopefully that helps!